# Git show doesn't work

Tags: git

When I run a Git command like this

```
git show 2cc9f40e99c34f9117a6feae3aa plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/modules/sfGuardAuth/templates/_signin_form.php
```

I usually get nothing. Sometimes I get something similar to what I'd see for `git diff` but usually it returns nothing. From what I understand, this is not the expected behavior. Am I doing it wrong or is Git messing up?

Comment: There will always be *some* output. Are you getting an error response?

Comment: No. I am really not getting any output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a colon between the SHA1 and the path:

```
git show 7b0a0e7:setup.py
git show 2cc9f40e99c34f9117a6feae3aa:plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/modules/sfGuardAuth/templates/_signin_form.php
```

Comment: Here's [specifying revisions in git-rev-parse](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html#_specifying_revisions).